# Visual Code: how to get intellisense of an object to work, when used as a reference in another object?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm working on some php project. I've noticed that once i create a reference in an object to another one, Visual code doesn't recognize the methods of the referenced object. For example:

```
require_once('../application/libraries/Processor.php');

    class Images{
        public function __construct($processor){
            $this->processor = new Processor();//intellisense DOES work
        }

        public function myFunc(){
            $this->processor->someFunc();//The intellisense does NOT work. 
        //If I hover over "processor", nothing appears.
        }
    }
```

I'm using "php intelephense" plugin. I remember that the issue was the same, when working with JS(no plugins).

Is there any workaround or plugin for this problem?